# How to get weather data from a weather station?

Tags: web-services, weather, weather-api, wunderground

I've been looking around how to get a historical data for a weather station.

There are two ID's for a station : 
- ISD (ex 074969) see http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/climate/isd/
- PWS (ex IFRANCEC5) see http://french.wunderground.com/weatherstation/about.asp

Either with wunderground.com nor forecast.io API am I able to get the weather recorded with this station on 1/1/13.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: What exactly does `I am not able...` mean? What have you tried - any exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That station didn't come online until August of 2013:
http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IFRANCEC5&day=1&year=2013&month=8&graphspan=month

Comment: Why wunderground does not update information with some stations during night? For example http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:00000.1.78482 is not updating during night and site just "estimate" conditions?